# install toilet flange extender after subfloor is installed or after finish floor

Tags: toilet, flange

Toilet flange is too low and needs a flange extender. Should it be installed after the subfloor ( the layer under the cement board for the tiled floor) is in place since it needs to be fastened into the subfloor?

Comment: I would just install the extender after the final flooring is in place since then you'll know how high it needs to extend.

Answer (score 0):

I'd install it after all the flooring is complete so you know exactly how much you need to extend.

You could use [one of these extension kits](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Oatey-Set-Rite-Plastic-7-125-in-in-Toilet-Flange-Extender-Kit-For/1000195003) and a wax ring once you know how much of a gap you need to fill. I don't like that the extender reduces the i/s diameter of the toilet drain. I avoid those wax rings with the plastic funnel/flange embedded in them for the same reason. I may just be superstitious, but I don't want to do anything that might restrict flow in that situation...

In stead of a flange extender, these kind of [extended seals](https://www.lowes.com/pd/danco-perfect-seal-universal-rubber-4-75-in-in-wax-free-gasket/50433626?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-rpe-_-google-_-lia-_-208-_-toiletrepair-_-50433626-_-0&store_code=1643&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5LeuuYWI5AIVWh-tBh0urAICEAQYAyABEgJ_4vD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) are also available. I don't have much first-hand experience with them, but I did use one similar to this (if not identical...I don't remember the brand..) a couple of years ago when replacing a toilet on a tile floor in my new house. So far, so good.